# How come my custummade Node doesn't seem to respond to modifications

Tags: css, javafx, controls

I made my own Node ,Knop,which extends from Button.
The moment I create a Knop ,I set its preferred size and want to give it a border on the sides. The moment I run my program I notice that the changes weren't put through and I fail to understand what might be the reason for it.

```
    private void initKnop(GridPane gp){
        veld = new Knop[DIM][DIM];
        for (int i=0;i<DIM;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<DIM;j++){
                Knop k =new Knop();
// the changes are done below
                k.setPrefSize(16, 16);
                try{
                Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream("Minesz.gif"));
                k.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));

                } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe){
                    System.out.println("minesz.gif niet gevonden");
                }

                k.setPrefSize(Labelsize, Labelsize);
                k.setStyle("-fx-background-image: Minesz.gif");
                k.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid");
                k.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 10px");
                veld[i][j]=k;
                gp.add(k , i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but my initial guess is that you haven't set a color for the border, which is transparent by default. Add this line:

`k.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black;");`

Comment: What does your Knop class look like?

Comment: Just an extends Button class. Nothing in particular.